Unable to add unsubscribe link to SendGrid Email Template
I'm am unable to add an unsubscribe link to my email template in SendGrid. The option to select an unsubscribe group is disabled, and when I try to add the group ID using .NET code, the email is sent without a clickable unsubscribe link. Has anyone else encountered this issue or have suggestions on how to resolve it? Thanks in advance!

I have attached screenshots for the reference


I've faced a similar issue before. Here’s what you can try:Check Unsubscribe Group: Make sure your unsubscribe group is set up and active in SendGrid under Marketing > Unsubscribe Groups.Update Your .NET Code: Ensure you're setting the asm.group_id correctly in your API call.
If adding manually, use [[unsubscribe]] in your HTML content.Test the Email: Send a test email to yourself and check how it appears in different email clients.If it still doesn’t work, it might be worth contacting SendGrid support.
